# Permitir carácter

Tags: javascript

Dispongo de la siguiente expresión regular, la cual valida un correo electrónico:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]*@[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/
```

Ejemplo: miusuario@gmail.com

Necesito para dicha regex, la forma de poder incluir un porcentaje (%) delante del @, siempre y cuando no sea ni en la primera, ni última posición, es decir:

```
%miusuario%@gmail.com -> INCORRECTO

miusu%ario@gmail.com -> CORRECTO
```

¿Alguien me ayuda? Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que esto consigue lo que deseas:

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}(%*[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_])*@[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/`

Como verás, el contenido del paréntesis es opcional, lo que dice es que el `%` es opcional, puede haber 0 o más, siempre que vayan seguidos del otro conjunto, que no permite paréntesis.

Para probar expresiones regulares te recomiendo: https://regexr.com/

Comment: Hola ArianJM, gracias por tu respuesta. Realmente no valdría, ya que justo antes del @ no se puede incluir. Entre medio del texto que hay antes del @ sí.

Comment: @user09b ¡ah!, claro. He actualizado mi respuesta, mira a ver ahora.

Comment: Funciona bien! En el caso de que en vez de % quisiera usar por ejemplo un +, sería igual? parece que da pattern error. Suponiendo otro caso. Disculpa las molestias.

Comment: El problema con el `+` es que tiene un significado especial en las expresiones regulares, por lo que tendrías que escaparlo. Para indicar el carácter `+`, usa `\+` en lugar de solo `+`.